# Method that maps colors to integers in Java

Tags: java, string, colors, int, bluej

I am working on my code for my Java class and I can't figure out how to create a method that accepts an int parameter and changes the color based on that int.
The question specifically asks us to:

> In your code, map each color to an integer (e.g. in my code 3 means green.) If the number passed to the method is not valid, change the color to red.The valid colors are "red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "magenta" and "black".

In other words, I am trying to select a string color using an integer. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried:

public void changeColor(int newColor)
    {

```
switch(color) {
    case 1:
    // color1
    case 2:
    // color2
    case 3:
    // color3
    default:
    //defaultcolor
}   
draw();
```

}

And I receive a compiler error saying;

incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

I apologize if I'm not inputting the code correctly. I am very new to programming.

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing this. For simplicity, I would recommend reading about [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statements.

Comment: I wouldn't use a switch. Just have a string array with the colors, let the user's input be the index to the color. Of course, you'd have to take into consideration humans usually use 1 as the "first" number.

Comment: I only recommended a `switch` because of the way this problem was structured (choose a color based on a number, and use a *default* color if the number is invalid).

Comment: This screams for an enum. Also useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch on color:

```
void selectColor(int color) {
    switch(color) {
    case 1:
        // color1
        break;
    case 2:
        // color2
        break;
    case 3:
        // color3
        break;
    default:
        //defaultcolor
    }   
}
```

However it would be better to define enum and pass it to this function instead int value.

Comment: I'm using blueJ as my IDE and with that code I'm getting a compiler error that states... incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: Can you share the line of code that's giving you that error?

Comment: Inside the case statement you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Roni'sRocket You should update your original post with the code you tried.

Comment: put a `break;` on each case, just to make sure it only goes through one case

Comment: On which line you get that error. Show that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

Shouldn't you be using `newColor` on your `switch`? (just basing it on your snippet. not too sure if you have another code in between.

Also, Put a `break` on your `case`s. Otherwise it will go through every case when applicable

```
         public void changeColor(int newColor) {

            switch(newColor) {
                case 1:
                  // color1
                  break;
                case 2:
                  // color2
                  break;
                 case 3:
                  // color3
                  break;
                 default:
                  //defaultcolor
                }   
                draw();
         }
```

Lastly, Based on your exception (int cannot be converted to java.lang.String), it looks like you are trying to convert an `int` to a `String` somewhere on your code. Try to use an `Integer` rather than the primitive `int`.

```
Integer number;
String numberInWords = Integer.toString(number);
```

instead of

```
int number;
```

Hope it helps.